# How to test if a shared pointer has been allocated but not assigned

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

For a shared pointer, how do I test whether it has been allocated but not yet assigned ?
For example:

Case 1. Create shared pointer using make_shared

```
std::shared_ptr<Entity> es = std::make_shared<Entity> ();
std::cout << "es: " << es.get() << std::endl;
if (es) {
    std::cout << "es assigned to something" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "es not assigned to something" << std::endl;
}
if (es.get() == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "es assigned to nullptr" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "es not assigned to nullptr" << std::endl;
}
```

Case 2. Create raw pointer which points to a nullptr. Point shared_ptr to this raw pointer

```
Entity* raw_entity_ptr2=nullptr;
std::shared_ptr<Entity> es2 = std::shared_ptr<Entity> (raw_entity_ptr2);

std::cout << "es2: " << es2.get() << std::endl;
if (es2) {
    std::cout << "es2 assigned to something" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "es2 not assigned to something" << std::endl;
}
if (es2.get()==nullptr) {
    std::cout << "es2 assigned to nullptr" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "es2 not assigned to nullptr" << std::endl;
}
```

Case 3. Create raw pointer which points to an instantiated object. Point shared_ptr to this raw pointer.

```
Entity* raw_entity_ptr=new Entity;
std::shared_ptr<Entity> es3 = std::shared_ptr<Entity> (raw_entity_ptr);

std::cout << "es3: " << es3.get() << std::endl;
if (es3) {
    std::cout << "es3 assigned to something" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "es3 not assigned to something" << std::endl;
}
if (es3.get()==nullptr) {
    std::cout << "es3 assigned to nullptr" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "es3 not assigned to nullptr" << std::endl;
}
```

produces the following output:

```
es: 0xa44de0
es assigned to something
es not assigned to nullptr

es2: 0
es2 not assigned to something
es2 assigned to nullptr

es3: 0xa44e20
es3 assigned to something
es3 not assigned to nullptr
```

How do I do a test which distinguishes between Case 1 and Case 3 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty bit of memory"?

Comment: Just what you are doing, if (es) : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool, note that assigning a nullptr to a shared_ptr will release its associated memory (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D) if ref count reaches 0 then memory is deleted

Comment: After your first line, `es` points to a dynamically allocated, value-constructed `Entity` (as if by `Entity{}`). Everything is properly initialized and there's no obvious assignment to be done, so could you clarify your question?

Comment: This is not related to `std::shared_ptr`, you must handle it from your object. For example, you could keep a `bool` to describe it your object has an assigned value or not.

Comment: The object either exists or it doesn't. There is no observable "exists but has not been assigned to" state.

Comment: I will edit to explain more clearly. Wait before commenting further.

Comment: A pointer (smart or not) has no idea about the state of your object, it stores the address and that's it. It is recommended to never allow invalid ("unassigned") states for your objects anyway, so you don't need to check it.

Comment: The only interesting case I can think of is where you only have a weak reference to an object which keeps the underlying memory alive (which in the `make_shared` use case can be quite a lot). Is this what you are worried about as this can be a major source of pain in specific circumstances.

Comment: @MikeVine a weak pointer is still either null or pointing to a `Entity`.

Comment: You can't distinguish between case 1 and case 3 because there is no difference between them. In both cases, you have a `shared_ptr` that owns a default-constructed `Entity`.

Comment: There is a difference between them, in case 1, the default constructor of Entity is not executed (I know because I have written the default constructor and have a std::cout in there to check if it is run or not).

Comment: @didjek [It is executed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf81aa4e47b9a873). You made a mistake somewhere when you checked.

Comment: @Caleth  a weak pointer to an expired object still uses all the memory in certain circumstances (which is bad), so its a very interesting thing to know. I was trying to ascertain whether this was what OP was asking.

Answer (score 3):

> how do I test whether it has been allocated but not yet assigned?

There is no mechanism in C++ to do that.

You really don't need to. Generally speaking, a `std::shared_ptr<Entity>` either points to a fully constructed `Entity` object, or it points nowhere.

If a default-constructed `Entity` is in a special "empty" state, it is up to the definition of `Entity` to provide a means for testing that.

E.g. (using `std::vector<int>` instead of `Entity`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>

int main() {
    auto es = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>> ();
    std::cout << "es: " << es.get() << std::endl;
    if (es) {
        std::cout << "es assigned to something" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "es not assigned to something" << std::endl;
    }
    if (es->empty()) {
        std::cout << "es is empty" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "es not empty" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

> What kind of test do I need to check that "es" points neither to nullptr NOR to an instantiated Entity object ?

There is no such test. In normal use, such a state is not possible. If you try to create a pointer value of type `Entity*` that is neither null nor points to an `Entity`, and then use that pointer value, the behaviour is undefined.

You can reinterpret cast a suitably aligned and sized `char[]` to `Entity*`, pass that to the constructor of `std::shared_ptr<Entity>` along with a suitable deleter, and then later on [placement-new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) an `Entity` there, but in the mean time you couldn't use the pointee of the shared pointer

Answer (score 2):

> What kind of test do I need to check that "es" points neither to nullptr NOR to an instantiated Entity object ?

There is no such test, because that is not a valid state for a pointer - not for `shared_ptr`, not for `unique_ptr`, not for *any* pointer.  There are only two valid states a pointer can have - pointing to valid memory, or `nullptr`. Anything else is invalid, and most uses of such a pointer are undefined behavior.

Comment: Not just dereferencing. If you `==` a invalid-valued pointer to another pointer that's also unspecified behaviour

Comment: when shared_ptr<Entity> sp = make_shared<Entity>() is executed, is sp pointing to valid memory ?

Comment: @didjek yes. it points to a default constructed `Entity`. The (zero in this case) arguments of `make_shared` are forwarded to the constructor